# How to stop parent list from scrolling but keep child list scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following scroll view

```
      CustomScrollView(
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Placeholder(
              fallbackHeight: 120,
            ),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 180,
              child: Placeholder(),
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: _NavigationList(
              items: routes.items,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Where I intend the parent list to not be scrollable but the nested list in the `SliverFillRemaining` should be scrollable.

But what ends up happening is that the `CustomScrollView` is still scrollable with the scroll bar and has quite a bit of overflow. The overflow seems to exactly match the height of the two placeholders combined. How can I make it so that the parent is not scrollable but the child is. Because now the scroll bar still shows up.

This is what it looks like. The app is full screen and there seems to be overflow and you can scroll using the scrollbar.

[image]

Btw I can't solve this with a column because it will cause overflow errors also. And if you try to solve it with an column and expanded then you would need to wrap the column with a SingleChildScrollView to prevent those error, which you can't do since there is an expanded in the Column.

**THE QUESTION:**

So very straightforward since I notice a misunderstanding of the issue in the answers. When you have a CustomScrollView and you add boxes with height and a SliverFillRemaining you would expect that there would not be any more overflow. This does seem to be the case and it matches the height of the boxes. And this is why the the parent CustomScrollView shows a scroll bar. My question is how do I prevent this.

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. Could you post a complete minimal sample (as OlegBezr did), so that we can run your exact code on our side?

Comment: mean using separate scrollable widget on body? can you include a gif what exactly you are trying to get

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. Why didn't you try removing CustomScrollView altogether and why your listview has one item NavigationList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I approached it differently. Since the parent list is only scrollable with the scroll bar I decided to disable the scroll bar for the parent list. It solves the issue I had.

But it still seems a bug to me that boxes with height added to a CustomScrollView with a SliverFillRemaining create overflow.

For now I will accept this as the answer.

```
      ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
          scrollbars: false,
        ),
        child: CustomScrollView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  Placeholder(
                    fallbackHeight: 120,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 180,
                    child: Placeholder(),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 25,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: ScrollConfiguration(
                behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
                  scrollbars: true,
                ),
                child: _NavigationList(
                  items: routes.items,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: this solution not work on flutter web .

Comment: It does, this is a web project. I have only been running this on web.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `hasScrollBody: false` to SliverFillRemaining? It should remove overflows

Comment: I did and it did not work

Comment: Could you publish the code to github? To try out the entire source?

Comment: I already found an answer it's posted above. I don't have too much time to do that now maybe later.

Answer (score 0):

With just using `SliverAppBar` you can achieve your desired output:
just make `pinned: true` and give `toolbarHeight: *as per your need*,`

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("CustomScrollView"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              //can change color as per your need or remove for default theme
              toolbarHeight: 350,
              // change height of appbar
              title: Column(
                children: const [
                  Placeholder(
                    fallbackHeight: 120,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 180,
                    child: Placeholder(),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 25,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                primary: false,
                itemCount: 20,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("navigation $index"),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is has nothing to do with the toolbar. The issue is that in a CustomScrollView when you add boxes with height and then you add a SliverFillRemaining that there is overflow on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use a `CustomScrollView` and two `sliver` sections to freeze the header and scroll down other side. Help comments can be found in my solution:

```
ScrollConfiguration(
        ///Note: below property help to scrolling without scrollbars and use code in web browsers.
        behavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior()
            .copyWith(scrollbars: false, dragDevices: {
          PointerDeviceKind.touch,
          PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        }),
        child: CustomScrollView(
          ///Note:  freeze headers on top by set below property .
          ///if delete this property ,may be header can scrolling and miss those .
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          slivers: [
            //Note: top section of CustomScrollView
            const SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Placeholder(
                fallbackHeight: 400,
              ),
            ),

            ///Note: other section of CustomScrollView - scrollable area
            /// if need scrollbar for here , can use  ScrollConfiguration widget !
            SliverFillRemaining(
              child: ListView(children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) ...[
                  Container(height: 100, color: Colors.green),
                  Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),
                ]
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

if using `ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false)` as a behavior for `ScrollConfiguration` , The scrollbars are removed, but your scrolling in flutter web remains disabled.
better use `MaterialScrollBehavior` widget like below:

```
const MaterialScrollBehavior()
            .copyWith(scrollbars: false, dragDevices: {
          PointerDeviceKind.touch,
          PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        })
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I made an example app with your code and it seems to be working as intended.
Please give it a try. I'm using flutter 3.3.9. If this does not help you, I would suggest posting the code of an example that fully reproduces your issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('CustomScrollView'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false),
          child: CustomScrollView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 120,
                      // child: GameSelectedIcon(),
                      child: Icon(Icons.garage),
                    ),
                    Placeholder(
                      fallbackHeight: 180,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 25,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SliverFillRemaining(
                child: ScrollConfiguration(
                  behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: true),
                  child: ListView(
                    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: [
                      ...List.generate(20, (int index) {
                        return TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Text('Navigate $index'),
                        );
                      }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just checked your example but it has the same issue. Added a gif in the question. You can still scroll and there is much overflow at the bottom. The gif was of a fullscreen flutter app.

Comment: I see. It works fine on phone emulators, that’s what I tested. I guess, you’re developing for desktop/web?

Comment: Aah I see, I can see how that was confusing. Added the flutter web tag.

Comment: I posted the answer back with edits. Added `ScrollConfiguration(behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(scrollbars: false)` on top of CustomScrollView - this disables the scrollbar, so your problem should be solved. Please give it a try

Answer (score -2):

If you don't intend the parent to scroll, then replace `CustomScrollView` with a `Column`, and make changes as below:

```
Column(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 120,
      child: GameSelectedIcon(),
    ),
    Placeholder(
      fallbackHeight: 180,
    ),
    SizedBox(
      height: 25,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          _NavigationList(
            items: _navigationListItems,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: This is not perse an answer to my question, since it's about the sliver fill remaining adding overflow when there are other boxes with height in the list. But that being said it works, except for the fact it introduces overflow errors now because of the column. So if you try to wrap your column in a single child scroll view to combat that overflow you'll get an error because there is an expanded trying to take the height when it's unbounded. This does not work without creating the overflow issues that I'm trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: @anonymous-dev Why would you need to add SingleChildScrollView, if you don't want it to be scrollable??

Comment: To prevent overflow. I found a solution to my problem and posted it as an answer.

Comment: @anonymous-dev I feel like your problem should have a simpler solution because if you don't want your parent to scroll then why would you even use a widget that is scrollable? Besides, using a CustomScrollView that is not scrollable along with SliverFillRemaining is equivalent to a Column with an Expanded widget, so I suggest you edit your question to include the complete class so everyone can understand the issue properly.

Comment: Because a column with an expanded widget will cause overflow errors when resizing the browser window.

Comment: So let's say if I would have used a Column in the example with a SingleChildScrollView wrapping it to prevent overflow. Then the questions wouldn't have been much different from what I have now. I think the issue is pretty clear from the gif.

Comment: @anonymous-dev ohh so the overflow was occuring on resizing, okay makes sense now.